# Left Join without duplicate rows from left table

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

Please look at the following query:

**tbl_Contents**

```
Content_Id  Content_Title    Content_Text
10002   New case Study   New case Study
10003   New case Study   New case Study
10004   New case Study   New case Study
10005   New case Study   New case Study
10006   New case Study   New case Study
10007   New case Study   New case Study
10008   New case Study   New case Study
10009   New case Study   New case Study
10010   SEO News Title   SEO News Text
10011   SEO News Title   SEO News Text
10012   Publish Contents SEO News Text
```

**tbl_Media**

```
Media_Id    Media_Title  Content_Id
1000    New case Study   10012
1001    SEO News Title   10010
1002    SEO News Title   10011
1003    Publish Contents 10012
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT 
C.Content_ID,
C.Content_Title,
M.Media_Id

FROM tbl_Contents C
LEFT JOIN tbl_Media M ON M.Content_Id = C.Content_Id 
ORDER BY C.Content_DatePublished ASC
```

**RESULT**

```
10002   New case Study  2014-03-31 13:39:29.280 NULL
10003   New case Study  2014-03-31 14:23:06.727 NULL
10004   New case Study  2014-03-31 14:25:53.143 NULL
10005   New case Study  2014-03-31 14:26:06.993 NULL
10006   New case Study  2014-03-31 14:30:18.153 NULL
10007   New case Study  2014-03-31 14:30:42.513 NULL
10008   New case Study  2014-03-31 14:31:56.830 NULL
10009   New case Study  2014-03-31 14:35:18.040 NULL
10010   SEO News Title  2014-03-31 15:22:15.983 1001
10011   SEO News Title  2014-03-31 15:22:30.333 1002
10012   Publish         2014-03-31 15:25:11.753 1000
10012   Publish         2014-03-31 15:25:11.753 1003
```

**10012 are coming twice...!**

My query is returning duplicate rows from tbl_Contents (left table in the join)

Some rows in tbl_Contents has more than 1 associated rows in tbl_Media.
I need all rows from tbl_Contents even if there are Null values exists in the tbl_Media BUT NO DUPLICATE RECORDS.

Comment: This is behaving as designed -- the rows aren't duplicated, they each have a different `media_id`.  In your example, which row would you keep?

Comment: You haven't Content_Id in you tbl_Media.

Comment: I agree there is no problem here. Those are two different rows.

Comment: Please check updated / corrected tbl_Media - now has Content_Id column, thanks

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try an [`OUTER APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT 
    C.Content_ID,
    C.Content_Title,
    C.Content_DatePublished,
    M.Media_Id
FROM 
    tbl_Contents C
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM tbl_Media M 
        WHERE M.Content_Id = C.Content_Id 
    ) m
ORDER BY 
    C.Content_DatePublished ASC
```

Alternatively, you could `GROUP BY` the results

```
SELECT 
    C.Content_ID,
    C.Content_Title,
    C.Content_DatePublished,
    M.Media_Id
FROM 
    tbl_Contents C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Media M ON M.Content_Id = C.Content_Id 
GROUP BY
    C.Content_ID,
    C.Content_Title,
    C.Content_DatePublished,
    M.Media_Id
ORDER BY
    C.Content_DatePublished ASC
```

The `OUTER APPLY` selects a single row (or none) that matches each row from the left table.

The `GROUP BY` performs the entire join, but then collapses the final result rows on the provided columns.

Comment: Using GROUP BY in this situation will result in rows being double counted if used in conjunction with aggregate functions like SUM or COUNT

Comment: Only if the aggregate functions do not appropriately account for that situation...

Comment: I think you forgot to add an aggregate function to your select for M.Media_Id. That columns will not collapse by itself. In this form the query should give an error imho.

Comment: @vargen_ that is accurate. I edited the answer to reflect a correct aggregation

Answer (score 27):

You can do this using generic SQL with `group by`:

```
SELECT C.Content_ID, C.Content_Title, MAX(M.Media_Id)
FROM tbl_Contents C LEFT JOIN
     tbl_Media M
     ON M.Content_Id = C.Content_Id 
GROUP BY C.Content_ID, C.Content_Title
ORDER BY MAX(C.Content_DatePublished) ASC;
```

Or with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT C.Content_ID, C.Contt_Title,
       (SELECT M.Media_Id
        FROM tbl_Media M
        WHERE M.Content_Id = C.Content_Id
        ORDER BY M.MEDIA_ID DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) as Media_Id
FROM tbl_Contents C 
ORDER BY C.Content_DatePublished ASC;
```

Of course, the syntax for `limit 1` varies between databases.  Could be `top`.  Or `rownum = 1`.  Or `fetch first 1 rows`.  Or something like that.

Comment: As I see form OP the table `tbl_Media` hasn't column `Content_Id`.

Comment: Please check updated / corrected tbl_Media - now has Content_Id column, thanks

Comment: Wont the performance of the correlated sub query be really bad? I've come across this sort of query on big result sets and it was terrible. An additional query is being executed for every row matched.

Comment: @mdon88 . . . The performance should be fine with an index on `tbl_Media(ContentId, Media_id)`.

Answer (score 11):

Using the DISTINCT flag will remove duplicate rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
C.Content_ID,
C.Content_Title,
M.Media_Id

FROM tbl_Contents C
LEFT JOIN tbl_Media M ON M.Content_Id = C.Content_Id 
ORDER BY C.Content_DatePublished ASC
```

Comment: adding `DISTINCT` to queries can be highly inefficient (in postgress with 5000+ rows, I've seen a 10 fold increase in the query time)

Answer (score 1):

The table tbl_media has the content_id 10012 appearing two times, so when tbl_content joins with tbl_media, it will capture 10012 twice, creating one row with media_id = 1003 and another one with media_id = 1000 (so if you consider both content_id and media_id, the information is actually not duplicated).

The question becomes, what is the correct media to prioritize for content 10012 (1000 or 1003)? Once you determine this relationship, you can adjust the IDs tbl_media and join the tables without creating duplicates on media_id level.

Answer (score 0):

This query gets content IDs from 10002-10012 without duplicates. Where there is more than one media ID for a content ID, it gets the first media ID found. To get the latest media ID, add `ORDER BY tbl_Media.Media_Id DESC` to the subquery in the `LEFT JOIN`.

[SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gwmRLAiabR2kve3fjsfba3/0).

```sql
-- Create tbl_Contents table
CREATE TABLE tbl_Contents (
    Content_Id INT,
    Content_Title VARCHAR(255),
    Content_Text TEXT,
    Content_DatePublished DATETIME
);

-- Insert data into tbl_Contents
INSERT INTO tbl_Contents (Content_Id, Content_Title, Content_Text, Content_DatePublished) VALUES
    (10002, 'New case Study',   'New case Study', '2014-03-31 13:39:29.280'),
    (10003, 'New case Study',   'New case Study', '2014-03-31 14:23:06.727'),
    (10004, 'New case Study',   'New case Study', '2014-03-31 14:25:53.143'),
    (10005, 'New case Study',   'New case Study', '2014-03-31 14:26:06.993'),
    (10006, 'New case Study',   'New case Study', '2014-03-31 14:30:18.153'),
    (10007, 'New case Study',   'New case Study', '2014-03-31 14:30:42.513'),
    (10008, 'New case Study',   'New case Study', '2014-03-31 14:31:56.830'),
    (10009, 'New case Study',   'New case Study', '2014-03-31 14:35:18.040'),
    (10010, 'SEO News Title',   'SEO News Text',  '2014-03-31 15:22:15.983'),
    (10011, 'SEO News Title',   'SEO News Text',  '2014-03-31 15:22:30.333'),
    (10012, 'Publish Contents', 'SEO News Text',  '2014-03-31 15:25:11.753');

-- Create tbl_Media table
CREATE TABLE tbl_Media (
    Media_Id INT,
    Media_Title VARCHAR(255),
    Content_Id INT
);

-- Insert data into tbl_Media
INSERT INTO tbl_Media (Media_Id, Media_Title, Content_Id) VALUES
    (1000, 'New case Study', 10012),
    (1001, 'SEO News Title', 10010),
    (1002, 'SEO News Title', 10011),
    (1003, 'Publish Contents', 10012);

-- Query (without duplicates)
SELECT
    tbl_Contents.Content_ID,
    tbl_Contents.Content_Title,
    tbl_Media.Media_Id
FROM tbl_Contents
LEFT JOIN tbl_Media ON tbl_Media.Media_Id = (
    SELECT
        tbl_Media.Media_Id
    FROM tbl_Media
    WHERE tbl_Media.Content_Id = tbl_Contents.Content_Id
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY tbl_Contents.Content_DatePublished ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to first run a select statement, then run an update or merge afterwards for any rows from `tbl_Media`