# php mysql: joining two tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have employeeinfo table and employeeloan table..
and i use this query:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"select tblemployeeinfo.employeeid, tblemployeeloan.amount from tblemployeeinfo left join tblemployeeloan on tblemployeeinfo.employeeid = tblemployeeloan.employeeid where tblemployeeinfo.employeeid = <employee id for example employee id 1>");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<br>".$row['employeeid'];
echo "<br>".$row['amount'];
}
```

the result is

```
employee id: 1
amount: 1000
employee id: 1
amount: 500
employee id: 1
amount: 100
```

but what i want is to display like this:

```
employee id: 1
amount: 1000
amount: 500
amount: 100
```

sorry for my bad english. tnx in advance

Comment: are you sure that your result has employee id ? I don't see that you'd selected it in your query

Comment: sorry sir... my bad i will edit my post.. supposedly that is tblemployeeid.employeeid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join without duplicate rows from left table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769641/left-join-without-duplicate-rows-from-left-table)

Comment: you may need to do "order by" since the query is join, and you need to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Normal hack can be done by below code

```
$i = 0 ;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if($i == 0)
        echo "<br>".$row['employeeid'];
    echo "<br>".$row['amount'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: thank you sir.. actually it works.. i will use it now in my code.. but if there is other way i am very glad to know it.. anyways tnx again sir..

Comment: could also check if mysql can do the job and work around this -> SELECT whatever_is_needed FROM table1  INNER JOIN table2  ON table1.otherid2=table2.otherid2 GROUP BY whatever_id