# Left Join without duplicate rows 1 to 1 join. Make each row in one table only join to one row in the other table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to join table 1 to table 2 to get table 3. (See desired output) However, I can't seem to get it to work since there are so many options since the table only contains one value. A left join doesn't seem to work.

I found this: [Left Join without duplicate rows from left table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769641/left-join-without-duplicate-rows-from-left-table/22769673)

which seems to match my use case, but Outer Apply is not in PrestoDB.

I essentially want to match each row in T1 with a single one in T2.

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t1.*, t2.col3
from t1 left join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col3 nulls last) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t2.col2 = t1.col2 and t2.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I made the sample T1,T2 as an example. In reality, I have multiple values of b all with values of c or null. Same with p - that example only filters for the one c value.

Comment: Gordon's logic fits your stated desired results. We can only give you what you ask for, and cannot pre-empt or imagine the rest of your data and requirements. Perhaps you'd like to expand your question to include some example data? (Or pre-create a SQLFiddle/DBFiddle link for us)

Comment: @apple1234 . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have *another* question, ask it as a *new* question, with appropriate details, sample data, and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have proper keys you get an m:n-join instead of 1:n. You can calculate a row number for both tables which acts (in combination with `col2`) as key for the following join:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3
from 
 (
   select t1.*, 
      row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col2) as rn
   from t1
 ) as t
left join
 (
   select t2.*, 
      row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col2) as rn
   from t2
 ) as t2
 on t1.col2 = t2.col2 
and t1.rn = t2.rn;
```