# LEFT JOIN Duplicating Rows

Tags: sql, presto

Table 1 has the join field (fieldY) duplicated many times within this table although every row in totality is unique.

When I try to run a `left join` I am getting 20x more rows than expected. I have tried to use solutions [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769641/left-join-without-duplicate-rows-from-left-table) with no luck.

My expectation is that the join would yield exactly as many rows as table1 without the join. The join would just bring in one more column (`fieldX`)

Any ideas?

```
SELECT 
    table1.*, table2.fieldZ
FROM
    table1
LEFT JOIN
    table2
ON
    table2.fieldX = table1.fieldY
WHERE
    criteria1 = '01/01/2019'
AND
    criteria2 > '0'
ORDER BY
    criteria2
```

---

In below photo:

`fieldz` = `Routing #`
`fieldX` = `Bank Account #` (*From table2*)
`fieldY` = `Bank Account #` (*From table1*)

[image]

*This can be joined by student ID or Bank Account #, but the problem is the same regardless because both Student ID & Bank Account # appear multiple times in Table 1`

Comment: For every table1.fieldY there will be as many rows as there are matching table2.fieldX from table2, or 1 if there is no matching.

Comment: If there are multiple rows in table2 with the same fieldx then that would be why you are seeing duplicates.

Comment: You can start with this test. This shouldn't return any rows. If it return any row, it will show you which fieldx value has duplicates on table2. If you have duplicates on table2, when you join it with table1 it will render duplicate rows of table1 (one for each relative value on table2).

    SELECT fieldx FROM table2 GROUP BY fieldx HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;

Comment: There was a typo in my post that may change this (importing `fieldz` and joining on `fieldx` & `fieldy`) @MarceloMyara. Sorry, just  started learning SQL **yesterday** lol

Comment: This does not make any difference. The condition `table2.fieldX = table1.fieldY` joins the tables. So there will be as many rows as there are matches between these columns.

Comment: Post sample data, because it is hard to understand what you mean by duplicates.

Comment: Fine, then for each row in table1 the column Car will match 1 or more rows of table2 on the column fieldX when the 2 columns are equal. This is how a join works.

Comment: @forpas I updated with an example of inputs and desired output

Comment: See my answer and check if you are doing something different

Answer (score 0):

Table2 must have Table 1's key across multiple records.  Needs to be 1:1 to achieve what you are describing.

Comment: Actually it doesn't need to be 1:1, it just needs to be unique to table2.

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
select t1.*, t2.routing 
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t2.studentid = t1.studentid
```

or this:

```
select t1.*, t2.routing 
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t2.bankaccount = t1.bankaccount
```

you get these results:

```
> studentid | bankaccount |  gpa | semester | routing
> --------: | ----------: | ---: | :------- | :------
>         1 |      123456 |      | Fall     | abc    
>         1 |      123456 |      | Spring   | abc    
>         1 |      123456 |      | Summer   | abc    
>         2 |      456789 |      | Fall     | def    
>         2 |      456789 |      | Spring   | def    
>         2 |      456789 |      | Summer   | def    
>         3 |      321654 |      | Fall     | ghi    
>         3 |      321654 |      | Spring   | ghi    
>         3 |      321654 |      | Summer   | ghi
```

You can check the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=23a7a8f6f35ba7d6de17bc497d2e45e0).

Comment: So is it the other arguments I have that are messing this up for me?

Comment: A WHERE clause does not increase the rows of a query.

Comment: You tagged only sql. Which dbms or tool are you using?

Comment: Presto which doesn’t appear to have a tag. I’m told it’s similar to raptor? Not sure though - I literally started SQL this week. I can’t figure this out for the life of me

Comment: I'm sure that either the data you are querying is different than what you think, or you are doing something wrong. Post the results you get also.